# How do I deal with color spaces and gamma in the PNG file format?

Tags: graphics, colors, png, libpng, color-space

Here's my problem:

I'm doing some rendering using spectral samples, and want to save an image showing the results. I am weighting my spectral power function by the CIE XYZ color matching functions to obtain an XYZ color space result. I multiply this XYZ color tuple by the matrix given by [this page](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html) for converting to sRGB, and clamp the results to `(0,1)`.

To save the image, I scale the converted tuple by 255 and cast it to bytes, and pass the array to libpng's `png_write_image()`. When I view a uniform intensity, pure-color spectrum rendered this way, it looks wrong; there are dark bands in the transitions between the colors. This is perhaps not surprising, because to convert from XYZ to sRGB, the color components [must be raised to 2.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_forward_transformation_.28CIE_xyY_or_CIE_XYZ_to_sRGB.29) after the matrix multiply (or linearly scaled if they are small enough). But if I do this, it looks *worse*! Only after raising to 1/2.2 does it start to look right. It seems like, in the absence of me doing anything, the decoded images are having a gamma of ~2.2 applied *twice*.

Here's the way I would expect it to work: I apply the matrix to XYZ, and I have a roughly energy-linear RGB tuple. I raise this to 2.2, and now have a perceptually linear color tuple. I encode these numbers as they are (thus making efficient use of the file precision), and store a field in the file that says "these bytes have been encoded with gamma 2.2". Then at image load time, the decoding system un-applies the encoded gamma, then applies the system gamma before display. (And thus from an authoring perspective, I shouldn't have to care what the viewer's system gamma is). But the results I'm getting suggest it doesn't work this way.

Worse, I have tried calling `png_set_gAMA()` with both 2.2 and 1/2.2 and see no difference in the image. I get similar results with `png_set_sRGB()` (which I believe should force the gamma to 1/2.2).
There must be something I have backwards or don't understand with regards to either how I should be converting my color values, or how PNG handles gamma and color spaces. To break this down into a few clarifying questions:

- What is the color space of the byte values I am expected to pass to `write_png()`?
- What calls, if any, must I make to libpng in order to specify the color space and gamma of the passed bytes, to ensure proper display? Why might they fail?
- How does the gamma field in the the png file relate to the exponent I have applied to the passed color channel values, if any?
- If I am expected to invert a gamma curve before sending my image data (which I doubt, but seems necessary now), should that inversion include the linear part of the sRGB curve?

Furthermore, I see hints that "white point" matters in conversion between XYZ and sRGB. It is unclear to me whether the matrices in the site given above include a renormalization to D65 (it does not match Wikipedia's matrix)-- or even when such a conversion is necessary. Most of the literature I've found glosses over the details. Is there yet another step in the conversion not mentioned in the wiki article, or will this be handled automatically?

Comment: Probably useful: https://hsivonen.fi/png-gamma/  and http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/articles/png-gamma.html

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty much the way you expected.  png_set_gAMA() causes libpng to write a gAMA
chunk in the output PNG file.  It doesn't change the pixels themselves.  A png-compliant
viewer is supposed to use the gamma value from the chunk, combined with the gamma of the display, to write the pixel intensity values properly on the display.  Most decoders won't actually do the two-step (unapply the image gamma, then apply the system gamma) method you described, although the result is conceptually the same:  It will combine the image gamma with the system gamma to create a lookup table, then use that table to convert the pixels in one step.

From what you observed (gamma=2.2 and gamma=1/2.2 behaving the same), it appears that you are using a viewer that doesn't do anything with the PNG gAMA chunk data.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> *because to convert from XYZ to sRGB, the color components must be raised to 2.4 after the matrix multiply...*

No, this is incorrect. Going from linear (XYZ) ***to*** sRGB, you do *NOT* raise to 2.4 nor 2.2, that is for going FROM sRGB to linear.

Going from linear to sRGB you raise to `^(1/2.2)` or if using the sRGB piecewise, you'll see  1/2.4 — the effective gamma you are applying is ^0.45455

On the wikipedia page you linked, this is the *FORWARD* transformation.

#### From XYZ to sRGB:

[image: sRGB Forward TRC math]

That of course being after the correct matrix is applied. Assuming everything is in D65, then:

[image]

### Straight Talk about Linear

Light in the real world is linear. If you triple 100 photons, you then have 300 photons. But the human eye does not see a trippling, we see only a modest increast by comparison.

This is in part why transfer curves or "gamma" is used, to make the most of the available code space in an 8 bit image (oversimplification on my part I know).

To do this, a linear light value is raised to the power of 0.455, and to get that sRGB value back to a linear space, then we raise it to the inverse, i.e. ^1/0.455 otherwise known as ^2.2

The use of the matrixes must be done in linear space. but after transiting the matrix, you need to apply the trc or "gamma" encoding. Based on your statements, no, things are not having 2.2 added twice, you are simply going the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: " It seems like, in the absence of me doing anything, the decoded images are having a gamma of ~2.2 applied twice. "

I think your monitor (hardwrare or your systems icc profile) has already a gamma setting itself.